# Is there a way to customize Docker's log?

Tags: docker, logging

We are collecting the logs of our applications. Since we containerize our applications, the way to collect logs needs a little bit changes.

We log via the Docker Logging Driver:

- Application output the logs to container’s stdout and stderr
- Using json-file logging driver, docker output logs to json file on
  the host machine
- Service on the host machine forwards the log files.

But the logs from Docker has additional information which unnecessary and make the forward step complicated because we need to remove those additional information before forward.

For example, the log from Docker is as below, but all we want is the value of log field. Is there a way to customize log format and only output the information wanted by override some Docker's configurations?

```
{
  “log”: "{“level”: “info”,“message”: “data is correct”,“timestamp”: “2017-08-01T11:35:30.375Z”}\r\n",
  “stream”: “stdout”,
  “time”: “2017-08-03T07: 58: 02.387253289Z”
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to customize the output of the `json-file` docker log plugin. However docker supports the `gelf` plugin which allows you to send logs to logstash. Using logstash you can output logs in many different ways (by using [output plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/output-plugins.html)) and at the same time customize the format.

For instance to output logs to a file (without any other metadata) you can use something like the following:

```
output {
 file {
   path => "/path/to/logfile"
   codec => line { format => "%{message}"}
 }
}
```

If you don't want to add complexity to your logging logic, you can keep using the `json-file` driver and use an utility such as `jq` to parse the file and extract only the relevant information. For instance with jq you can do: `jq -r .log </path/to/logfile>`

This will read each line of the specified file as a json object and output only the `log` field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Actually on Step 3, we planned to use Splunk Forwarder to forward all the logs to Splunk server and Splunk Forwarder supports Sed command to extract logs.